# concatenation of ABRICATE csv results in snakemake file

Tags: python, csv, snakemake

I would like to concatenate multiple csv files results from the program ABRICATE (github.com/tseemann/abricate) into a single csv file.

The following snakefile runs through a folder of fasta files producing an individual csv for each fasta. I would like to concatenate those results into a single csv file, but not sure how to frame "rule all".

Any suggestions?
Below is my working snakefile.  Thanks

```
########################### snakefile making dictionary
import os
import yaml

file_list = []
### location assumes that data is in results_fasta/ folder
for entry in os.scandir("results_fasta/"):
    if entry.is_file():
        file_list.append(entry.name)

#### this tells split the file for use in dictionary creation
config_dict = {"samples":{i.split(".")[0]:"results_fasta/"+i for i in file_list}}

with open("config_abricate_resfinder.yaml","w") as handle:
    yaml.dump(config_dict,handle)

###### dictionary created using all files located in results_fasta folder
configfile: "config_abricate_resfinder.yaml"

##### not needed but used to say what is currently running
print("Starting abricate workflow")

##### rule all is a general rule that says this is the results we are lookin for in the end.
rule all:
    input:
        expand("abricate_resfinder/{sample}_abricate_resfinder.csv", sample = config["samples"])

##### Abricate resfinder
rule resfinder:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
    params:
        db_resfinder = "leaveblank",  ### for resfinder DB is default so leave blank
        type = "csv"
    output:
        res = "abricate_resfinder/{sample}_abricate_resfinder.csv",
######## log file is empty.  need to print stdout to log
    log:
        "logs/{sample}_resfinder.log"
    shell:
        "abricate {input} --{params.type} > {output.res}"
```

Comment: If the csv file has no header, that would be trivial. Anyway, the first question is if the number of fields and the fields themselves match in each individual file?

Comment: yes, all fields match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files have no headers and the fields match, the concatenation may be done by `cat` command:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("abricate_resfinder/{sample}_abricate_resfinder.csv", sample = config["samples"])
    output:
        out.csv
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

If there are headers, you need to think first what result you actually need. The simplest would be to remove all headers at all. You may try this:

```
    "cat {input} | sed '/^#/d' > {output}"
```

Comment: If you want to keep the first header, I would use an awk command such as `awk 'NR < 2 {print $0 ; next} !/^#/{print $0}'` instead of sed.

Comment: @Dmitry. So in your example are you making a new rule with  shell:  "cat {input} > {output}" ?

Comment: @JacobALSDURF I'm adding the `shell` section into your existing rule.

Comment: @TroyComi There are multiple ways to do that. My solution is a quick and dirty.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov "rule all"  is the target rule that the follow rules work towards.  Target rule is not meant to have directives.

Comment: @JacobALSDURF your question starts with "I would like to concatenate multiple csv files..." -- so your target is a single file. You may split my implementation into two, but nothing requires the "target rule" to have no directives.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov  Your solution of adding cat {input} > {output} to the rule all worked.  Thanks